# Dynamics CRM: What is the use of Following Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2016

```
Guid regardingobjectid = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
string regardingobjectidtype = "lead";
follow["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference(regardingobjectidtype, regardingobjectid);
```

1) in 1st Line the "id" present in the OUTPUTPARAMETERS is converted into string type. exactly what is stored in the variable called "regardingobjectid". and why GUID type is used.

2)Look at this..
 ""EntityReference(regardingobjectidtype, regardingobjectid)"" line
how the compiler will compare string"lead" (regardingobjectidtype) and 
the value stored in the "regardingobjectid".

The value stored in the "regardingobjectid" will be like 
"b23737-sadf-3251-asgf" in this format right

Answer (score 1):

Attribute "regardingobjectid" of Entity "follow" (which is your `follow`) is of type `EntityReference` and `EntityReference` contains both entity name (which is "lead" in this case) and record id (which for all CRM entities is GUID). I don't know what do you mean by "how the compiler will compare string and guid", there is no such comparison made anywhere in the code (maybe you meant assignment? But in that case it's `EntityReference` which is being assigned, so everything is just fine). GUID is an identifier format used for all Dynamics CRM entities.

Comment: Entity reference will take two parameters, i.e Name and Guid.            and that guid is assigned with entity name right.?

Comment: No, guid is unique, entity name is name of entity like "lead", "account", "contact" etc. It's called logical name.

Comment: what exactly "EntityReference("entity name", guid) will do.

Comment: `new EntityReference("entity name", guid)` will create an object of type EntityReference with logical name of entity name and Id equal to provided guid. Have you ever read MSDN documentation? Either you don't understand c# code and you should read some tutorials first or you should read basic documentation for CRM SDK...